# Getting the Intersection of Two Custom Taxonomy Terms for a Custom Post Type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, get-posts

(**Moderators note**: Was originally titled *"How to get_posts of a custom post type that is in two custom taxonomies?"*)

I have a custom post type that has two taxonomies which are separate, one called *"Project Type"* and one called *"Package"*. I need to get a list of projects which are of *"Project Type"* `A` **and** *"Package"* `A`. I tried using following code:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'portfolio', 
  'numberposts' => -1, 
  'project_type' => 'A', 
  'package' => 'A'
); 
$my_posts = get_posts($args);
```

But this gets all the posts that are *EITHER* in Project Type A OR Package A.

Is there any way to say in `get_posts()` that I want to return only those posts that are in *BOTH* taxonomies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of v1.3, the [Query Multiple Taxonomies](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/) plugin works great with WP_Query. Your original args work as is.

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'portfolio',
'numberposts' => -1,
'project_type' => 'A',
'package' => 'A'
);
```

Then make a new query and check it:

```
$foo = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($foo->posts);
```

I tested this on my own custom taxonomy setup, and it only returned posts which matched **both** terms in the query.

Another convenient method of grabbing multiple taxonomy terms with QMT is building simple URL queries:

```
site.com/?post_type=portfolio&package=foo&project=bar
```

I've used this method with the `add_query_args()` function to create links on a page that modify the current query, refining it by adding additional terms and taxonomies. The syntax also works great with a search input, as multiple words in the input field are posted as foo+bar, which works great with QMT:

```
site.com/?post_type=portfolio&project=alpha&colors=red+blue+green
```

Which returns only posts that meet **all** these criteria - Type: Portfolio / Project: Alpha / Colors: red + blue + green

Answer (score 4):

Hi **@shaun**:

*@Rarst* is right in that they are [adding this functionality to WordPress v3.1](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12891), but it won't be here for a while and I'm sure you need it now. You could try to [grab the code they are working on](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12891#attachments) and try to make it work, you could use [the plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/) both *@Rarst* and *@somatic* mention, or you could just include the code you need into your theme, below.

The following code is a `posts_where` hook to add a `tax_terms` query variable with a value of the format *(i.e. colon-commas)* where the values are term [slugs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Slug):

```
"{$varname1}:{$value1},{$varname2}:{$value2},...{$varnameN}:{$valueN}"
```

This is a self-contained `.php` you can drop into the root of your website to test it out before pulling the `add_action` call and the `tax_terms_where()` function into your theme's `functions.php` file *(or into the `.php` file of one of your own plugins.)*

```
<?php
/*
* Adds "tax_terms" to WP_Query()
*
* See: http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2010-October/035258.html
* See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2255/
*
*/

  header('Content-Type:text/plain');
  include "wp-load.php";
  add_action('posts_where','tax_terms_where',10,2);

  $result = new WP_Query('post_type=portfolio&tax_terms=project_type:A,package:A');
  foreach($result->posts as $post) {
    echo "{$post->post_title}\n";
  }

function tax_terms_where($where,$wp_query) {
  if (isset($wp_query->query)) {
    $query = $wp_query->query;
    if (is_string($query))
      parse_str($query,$query);
    if (is_array($query) && isset($query['tax_terms'])) {
      global $wpdb;
      $tax_terms = explode(',',$query['tax_terms']);
      foreach($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
        list($taxonomy,$term) = explode(':',$tax_term);
        $sql = <<<SQL
AND $wpdb->posts.ID IN (
  SELECT tr.object_id
  FROM $wpdb->term_relationships AS tr
  INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
  INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms AS t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
  WHERE tt.taxonomy='%s' AND t.slug='%s'
)
SQL;
        $where .= $wpdb->prepare($sql,$taxonomy,$term);
      }
    }
  }
  return $where;
}
```

If this isn't exactly what you need because, for example, you'd rather match the `$term->term_id` instead of matching the `$term->slug` then the code shouldn't be too hard to modify for your needs, assuming you are comfortable with SQL and `.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Old Q, but apparently comes up so here is current state — taxonomy queries got much improved in 3.1 and further since.

These days it will easily be handled with tax query using `AND` relationship, example from Codex:

```
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'movie_genre',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => array( 'action', 'comedy' ),
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'actor',
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms'    => array( 103, 115, 206 ),
        'operator' => 'NOT IN',
    ),
),
```

See [Taxonomy Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) for full documentation.

---

Usual disclaimer - I hadn't messed with custom stuff myself so far.

I think complex taxonomy queries are not implemented in WP core (yet). Try [Query Multiple Taxonomies](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/) plugin.

Comment: Hmm.. initial testing with this has shown that it is not working. Not sure if it is because I am using get_posts ?

Comment: `get_posts()` and `query_posts()` accept same parameters so it should be fine.