# WP 3.0.5 - Custom posts matching 2 taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I'm running a WP 3.0.5 website and here is my problem: I define a custom post type with 2 custom taxonomies and I've got to develop a search engine based upon these taxonomies. Until there, no problem :

```
$args = array(
         'my_post_type' => 'post_type_name',
         'my_taxo_1' => 'taxo-1-slug',
         'my_taxo_2' => 'taxo-2-slug'
);

query_posts( $args );
```

Working like a charm! But... What I want is to retrieve only custom posts matching both taxonomies whereas here, only 1 is sufficient.

I saw WP 3.1 is introducing a new way dealing with taxonomies (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Taxonomy_Parameters) which will absolutely solve my problem but WP 3.1 is still in beta and I can't take risk for my customer.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You're way in the future, 4.0.5, I think you're talking about 3.0.5 ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the Intersection of Two Custom Taxonomy Terms for a Custom Post Type?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2255/getting-the-intersection-of-two-custom-taxonomy-terms-for-a-custom-post-type)

Comment: It seems I need rest ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in 3.0 with [the Query Multiple Taxonomies plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is basically the same as this question:

- [**Getting the Intersection of Two Custom Taxonomy Terms for a Custom Post Type?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2255/getting-the-intersection-of-two-custom-taxonomy-terms-for-a-custom-post-type/2942#2942)

Comment: In that case, we should vote to close it as a duplicate. I know you have the moderator-vote-of-death, but I think this is so clear that you don't have to wait for others to get to five votes.

Comment: You're actually right. I didn't find this one. Thanks.

Comment: @Jan Fabry - I'm not a huge fan of closing duplicates but they different questions tend to have different titles and different text those they SEO differently. I also think the concept of *"duplicates"* is subjective and see that some *"duplicates"* get closed and others don't. Cross-referenced *"duplicates"* can also provide more context for a question. Basically I don't think that is a good rule of StackExchange so I let others close duplicates if they really want to.

Comment: But when you close this question as a duplicate, the question will still exist, only it will have a clear link to the "reference" question. And more important: if there are multiple solutions for a problem, they will all appear as answers on one question page, and not be spread out over multiple questions. Now your answer and link will not be at the top of this page, because my answer (which is not always the best, depending on the situation) appears above it. But I guess this should be a Meta discussion if we want to continue it.

Comment: @Jan Fabry - If you feel this is an important enough issue to devote time to then by all means take to meta.